# Shell : How to get a container's name containing some string

Tags: bash, shell, powershell, docker

I have a list of containers where names are like following :

**container 1**: myApp_**ihm**.dfgdfgdfgdfvdfdfbvdfvdfv

**container 2**: myApp_back.uirthjhiliszfhjuioomlui
 ...

**container 3:** myApp_database.piyrjfhjyukyujfkgft

I have to execute some string on the container where the name contains **ihm** (the first one in my example)

In order to exec my commands , I'm used to do:

```
 docker exec -it ihm bash
```

so `ihm` should by replaced by some test to get the first one name :

**myApp_ihm.dfgdfgdfgdfvdfdfbvdfvdfv**

**Suggestions?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep myApp_ihm | awk '{print $1}') /bin/bash
```

Comment: You can also use this : docker exec -it $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep prestashop_boutique | awk '{print $1}') /bin/bash
Same result but It use container name and not container ID

Answer (score 2):

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep "ihm") bash
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, added that to a bash script and saved myself 30-60 seconds of typing/copy-pasting every time I want to go into my container.

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Command}}" | grep /home/app/ | awk '{print $1}') /bin/bash
```